# Google Apps Marketplace request -- status?

Tags: google-apps-marketplace, chrome-web-store

After creating both a Chrome Web Store listing as well as a duplicate listing tuned for the Google Apps Marketplace, I have filled out the Marketplace Listing Review Request.  I've had to edit the second listing several times as I've uncovered issues like not including the app member in the manifest, and I have no idea of the overall status of the request.  Is there a way to find out?

My big concern is that something is still not right or that I might have missed a step or done something else wrong in the process of submitting the listing.  Since there's no obvious validation around the Marketplace Listing Review request, I'm not 100% sure if I'm doing it perfectly.  This is my first listing.  Help?

Comment: What is your Chrome Web Store Item ID? You can find it in the developer dashboard.

Comment: does this look right? lclencgjgmjdbdaokgkagighbkeblicc

Answer (score 0):

First step would be to provide your Chrome Web Store Item ID as jonathanberi mentioned. Once you do that I can take a look at the application for you.

The reality is that we don't check and test new GAM applications every single day. It's more accurate to say that your application will be checked within 1-2 weeks from publication. If there are any issues, I or someone else on the curation team, will reach out to you to let you know of the problem and it's severity. Most of the time the issues aren't serious enough to warrant immediate removal from the Google Apps Marketplace and simply need to be fixed within a 30 day time frame.

So, long story short, no news is good news for GAM publications. If you don't hear anything from us within 2-3 weeks of your publication date, you can safely assume that your application has met all of our listing requirements.

Comment: I'm trying to search for our app in the Google Apps Marketplace (https://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace) and it's not coming back.  How can I make sure we're able to be found in this location?

Comment: @Paul McCloud: Does Google still accept GMail addons? I've been trying to publish my addon for almost a year now.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55935310/is-it-still-possible-to-publish-a-gmail-addon

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems and spoke to some very helpful folks at Google. Here is a summary of what they said:

**Time taken to hear back:** For new submissions their SLA for reviewing is 8 business days, but they usually do better than that.

**Time taken for your app to show up on Google Apps Marketplace:** 12-24 hours. When they approve an item it is automatically send to the public store, however it takes time to be shown in the Google Apps Marketplace search results due to cache propagation as time is taken for their robots to find it, index it and get it ready. (as of Jan 2017)