# Is it still possible to publish a Gmail addon?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-addons

I've been trying to publish a Gmail add-on for half a year now. But I can't submit it, because the required option is disabled:
[image]

I've seen the other postings about this and registered at the [doc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50281462/3887520) and the [issue tracker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50229354/3887520), but got no response at all.

Did I make a configuration mistake, causing the option the be disabled?
Or is it simply not possible any more to publish Gmail add-ons?

(Sorry, I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask, but the official Google pages do link here...)

Comment: Have you explicitly created a Google Cloud Platform project to be associated with your Apps Script project?  The Apps Script project and GCP project are two different things.  They must be associated with each other and be connected.  From the [https://console.cloud.google.com/home](https://console.cloud.google.com/home) page, choose IAM & Admin and then choose "Manage Resources"  From there you can click the "Create Project" button.  Have you done that?

Comment: @Alan Wells: Thanks. This is confusing. I have a project in the combo box in the "Google cloud platform" header, but it's not listed on the "Manage resource" page. I created a new one, now both (old+new) are in the combo box. I cannot reach the checkbox mentioned in the question for the new project without going through OAuth confirmation, which takes weeks. So I'm unsure if this try is worth it, if there's something wrong with my old project.

Comment: I've created a YouTube video that shows how to associate an Apps Script project with a GCP project.  [Add an Apps Script project to a GCP project - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vEDUt7aj15k)

Comment: @Alan Wells: Thanks for putting so much work into this. Unfortunately, your video shows exactly the problem that I was asking about. At 12:20 you can see the disabled "Gmail add-on extension" checkbox. Looks like you can't publish a Gmail add-on either... ;-)

Comment: Yah, I know.  haha.  I noticed that also.  I just re-published another add-on, and noticed that the GMail Add-on check box is not grayed out, but I don't know what the difference is.  Did you fill out the [Gmail Add-ons Submission Information](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdQD9F5TXZvlpQcY1I6fvaZqLvULG1THhou3y5IpRRwjgwZYg/viewform)

Comment: Yes, did that last December. Twice. No reaction. :-(

Comment: There is a note in the [Publishing Gmail Add-ons](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publishing-gmail-addons) documentation stating: `We are currently restricting the number of public Gmail add-ons that appear in the G Suite Marketplace.`  It would be nice if Google would let people know what the current status is when you go through the publishing process.  But obviously there is a failure of Google somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

From [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50281462/1595451) by Alejandro Tamalet

> Please note that currently to publish a Gmail add-on the listing has to be domain private or whitelisted, see https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/how-tos/publish.

Comment: Thanks, I already applied for whitelisting in December 2018. No response whatsoever. That's why I'm asking, if it's still possible at all to submit an add-in.

Comment: I don't think that you "apply" for whitelisting.  The documentation states that whitelisting consists of adding the url to the project manifest.  The manifest has two fields that can be used: 1) `gmail.openLinkUrlPrefixes` and 2) `urlFetchWhitelist`  If your add-on is making an external request, and you don't whitelist the url in the project manifest file, then you probably won't get approved.

Comment: You do have to apply for whitelisting. Quote: "Once the review process is complete and you have received the review team's approval, they whitelist your add-on for publication." (Btw, I'm already using gmail.openLinkUrlPrefixes.)

Comment: You are correct.  It's true that the documentation states that the review team "whitelists" your add-on.  Unfortunately, the term "whitelist" is also used to describe a situation for the account that installed your add-on to whitelist your add-on.  So, there are two different situations for which the term "whitelisting" is used.  I think of the process of getting the add-on publicly published, in terms of "approval" after "Requesting a Review."  So, I misunderstood what you were stating.